# After writing formulae into excel sheet with xlwt, reading cells with formulae by xlrd returns blank

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, xlrd

I have first created a Pivot Table using pandas. Then I saved it to a worksheet. Then I wrote some data & formulae in this worksheet using xlwt for further processing. Now I am trying to read value from a cell to which I had previously written a formula.

```html
book = xlrd.open_workbook(fname)
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Pivot Table')
print 'Spare',sheet.cell(11,10).value
```

This code works fine and it returns proper values when pointing to a cell without a formula (that depends on other cells). But the cells with formulae return nothing.

I need a way to read the cell value. The excel sheet has a lot of formulae written to it and the cell I am trying to read is the final cell. So I do not want to back-track the process to get the value (compute through my script).

I am using Ubuntu and have LibreOffice. (FYI, In case there is no direct way and we need to open excel and fetch the data)

Comment: I inserted raw_input() before I read the excel file. Then edited and saved it. Got the right cell value.
I am writing the script for my boss. So still need a way around. Need the script to handle everything.

Comment: An Excel file does not contain the functionality required to calculate any formulas it contains - that is done by the Excel application...

Comment: Please provide an example excel file so the problem can be reproducable.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done.

After writing to excel by xlwt package, you need to open the excel and save it. Opening the excel file will populate the cells containing formulae with the calculated values. Then saving the excel will save these values to the cells along with the formulae.

Some things I observed-

1. The above is true only for cells with formulae that use values in other cells. If I try to read the cells with formulae like '=10+2' or something, this returns the right value.
2. After opening the excel, you will need to edit/add something to enable the save button/option.